# react native is not working with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I am super new to Redux and I tried creating a simple react-native application and included `redux`, but I am completely blocked by the following issue. I am not getting any proper solution to my problem.

[image: React redux error]

I tried googling but all the solutions are asking about setting NODE_ENV to `production`, but I'm not on production environment. I am getting this error on my development machine.

Comment: how did you include redux? is that the only thing you added?

Comment: I npm installed redux and react-redux libraries

Comment: hmm I'm not getting such an issue on a brand new react-native app. can you list which versions of everything you are using?